# Automatically create tag after PR based on new version string discovered in source code

Tags: version-control, continuous-delivery

I have a Python package hosted on GitHub. My current non-automated workflow is that I

- create a feature branch
- create a PR (on GitHub) feature -> main
- update code (on pushes to the PR branch some CI linting/testing runs)
- Once the update is near completion I

  1. manually version bump `__version__` in `__init__.py` and
  2. manually update `CHANGELOG.rst` to reflect the new version and changes therein.
- Merge the PR from feature branch into main
- On my local repo, I create a tag on the new commit on the main branch matching the new `__version__` in `__init__.py`. Then I push this tag to GitHub

Could someone point me to/recommend a tool that automates the last step? I've found a number of tools which advertise themselves as parsing the commit logs and source code to *infer* the next version number and then update it in the source and create a tag. But I don't want the tool to infer the version number and bump it in source + tag, I want it to find the version number in the source and create the tag.